# INSERT если такое значение есть (не по ключу)

Tags: mysql

Доброго

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `account` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES ('1','2','3');
```

Как, и можно ли построить запрос, что бы INSERT сверял есть ли в таблице b=2, и если есть, запрос не делал? b - не является уникальным полем в таблице

p.s. да и хэлп мне не помог, хотя с mysql вроде не первый год, аж обидно ((

Comment: Для этого случая хорошо подошел бы механизм [merge'а][1]. В oracle он точно есть, а вот в MySQL - не знаю?!


  [1]: http://www.google.ru/url?q=http://www.sql.ru/forum/954484/podskazhite-s-operatorom-merge&sa=U&ei=oWlnU_G0FqfV0QXokICgCg&ved=0CCMQFjAB&sig2=8YXmwF00iFkV9Yo_8zo-Ag&usg=AFQjCNFKA41bml-HK6aAGmryX2-rgOkxpA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать, если вместо VALUES заполнять из таблицы, хотя это и хак чистой воды:

```
INSERT INTO `account` (`a` ,  `b` ,  `c`)
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT '1', '2', '3'
) x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 
FROM `account` 
WHERE `b` = '2'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте:

```
IF (SELECT b FROM t t WHERE t.b IS NOT NULL ) THEN INSERT INTO `account` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES ('1','2','3')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ID=2; // как пример
$sql="SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE ID='{$ID}'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_row($result)<=0){ 
  данной строки нет - делаем INSERT
else{
 Строка дублируется, либо ничего не делаем, либо как решите сами
}
```